# webRequest for MVC URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am using below code to get my data from some website

`HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL); 
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();`

I successfully get data when the URL points to some pdf page but when i try above code with an MVC project URL `ex: http://domain.com/controller/action?parameter=xyz`, i get 404 error. My presumption is `parameter` part is ignored when its requesting data thus i get `page not found` status.

I can access the path in browser without any problem but it errors out when using webRequest.

Have anyone come across this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Action you are trying to get is marked as HttpPost. If it is, this code, between the two lines, should solve the problem:

```
webRequest.Method = "POST";
```